# Access Denied Error when connecting to SAP Logon through Blue Prism

Tags: sap-gui, blueprism

Created SAP Logon object using Win32 spying. Elements were identified correctly but when I try to run the bot, I get an access denied error shown below. Any idea what's going on and how I can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run a process unattended and face this issue, it's normally due to a lock screen. Try logging in using BP's login agent first, then run your process